# Correct path PHPMailer XAMPP Mac

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

My htdocs in XAMPP have my project folder, which contains the PHPMailer folder downloaded from github.

In my project folder I also have a file, test.php:

```
<?php

require('/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

// Send mail using Gmail
if($send_using_gmail){
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl"; // sets the prefix to the servier
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
    $mail->Port = 465; // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
    $mail->Username = "myemail@gmail.com"; // GMAIL username
    $mail->Password = "mypw"; // GMAIL password
}

// Typical mail data
$mail->AddAddress($email, $name);
$mail->SetFrom($email_from, $name_from);
$mail->Subject = "My Subject";
$mail->Body = "Mail contents";

try{
    $mail->Send();
    echo "Success!";
} catch(Exception $e){
    // Something went bad
    echo "Fail :(";
}

?>
```

This is returning this error:

```
Warning: require(/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/My_Project/test.php on line 3

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php') in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/My_Project/test.php on line 3
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: check you path to PHPMailer.php

Comment: I'm aware it;s a path problem - but is my syntax correct? And which file should I be aiming for?

Comment: Yeah, It's look like everything okay. But I recommends you to install all packages via composer.

Answer (score 0):

As Oleg said, you should use use composer, but your specific problem is probably the leading slash on the path which makes it absolute, so change it to:

```
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
```